# How to remove calculator buttons from numeric keypad

Tags: android

The input type for my EditText control is set to "number." When the numeric keypad is displayed, besides showing the numbers, it also shows calculator keys (+/-/etc.). I am wondering if there is any setting to remove the calculator keys.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need are actual numbers 0-9 you could set your keyboard type to "phone" instead of "number" which should give you a more 9-pad style keyboard that probably won't contain the extra keys like +, - etc...

However in the end it is up the currently running keyboard application (which is chosen by the user) If whatever keyboard they happen to be using shows keys that you would rather it not, there is generally no way for you to instruct it not to show those keys.

If you want to have complete control over the input then you'll have to create your own View that mimics the functionality of the keyboard and "manually" insert the typed characters into your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This doesn't help much. I still get the keys, although a few different ones that before. Regards.